# Sending python URL requests and looping through a range in the data

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to send the following request in python to a API with data and see the response. This will return a JSON with some values. However, i am trying to loop through the values i send to the URL

```
import requests

for i in range(1,10):
  data = '{"id":i}'
  response = requests.post('https://myurl.com', data=data)
  print(response.text)
```

This doesn't work and says

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: 
Unrecognized token \'i\': was expecting (\'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: 
(byte[])\"{\"id\":i}\"; line: 1, column: 9]"}
```

However, if i hardcode the python script like below, then i get the desired JSON response. So not sure why looping through values is not working.

```
data = '{"id":1}'
```

What am i doing wrong? Appreciate any help.

Comment: That does not appear to be a valid string formatting attempt.  Perhaps look up fstrings again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop doesn't seem correct.

```
for i in range(1,10):
  data = '{"id":i}'
```

Outputs

```
{"id":i}
{"id":i}
{"id":i}
{"id":i}
{"id":i}
{"id":i}
{"id":i}
{"id":i}
{"id":i}
```

Change `data` into `data = f'{{"id":{str(i)}}}'` to get

```
{"id":1}
{"id":2}
{"id":3}
{"id":4}
{"id":5}
{"id":6}
{"id":7}
{"id":8}
{"id":9}
```

Comment: Perfect that was it. Thanks for quick response.